# rudimentary java related issue

Tags: java, exception, io, stack-trace

i've started experiencing this exceptional, unprecedented problem as of today

my program stops accepting input after a certain point and unusually terminates

here's the excerpt:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try
  {
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  String a=sc.nextLine();
  String b=sc.nextLine();
  String c=sc.nextLine();
  String d=sc.nextLine();
  String e=sc.nextLine();
  int f=sc.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
     System.out.printf("%s,%s,%s%n3",a,b,c);
    }
    // TODO, add your application code
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }catch (Exception cause) {
StackTraceElement elements[] = cause.getStackTrace();
for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {       
    System.err.println(elements[i].getFileName()
        + ":" + elements[i].getLineNumber() 
        + ">> "
        + elements[i].getMethodName() + "()");
}
```

}

i have tried to access Stack Trace information above to figure out what has gone wrong with my jdk or some other software that might be causing this problem

this is the output that the afore-mentioned code generates

Scanner.java:864>> throwFor()

Scanner.java:1485>> next()

Scanner.java:2117>> nextInt()

Scanner.java:2076>> nextInt()

pester.java:21>> main()

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Simply do `cause.printStackTrace()` in the catch block, and post here what you get

Comment: What's all that stuff in the catch block?  Just print the stack trace: e.printStackTrace();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe is your `nextInt()` call since it doesn't consume the Return Line... Add an extra `nextLine()` (don't have to assign it to anything)

Also as explained by @cdhowie nextInt() has to consume an Integer value as your sixth input.

Comment: i've reduced the number of inputs restricting them to just 1 data type i.e. String and after an attempt at executing this amended code:



public static void main(String[] args) {
      try
      {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      String a=sc.nextLine();
      String b=sc.nextLine();
      String c=sc.nextLine();
     for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
     {
      System.out.printf("%s,%s,%s%n",a,b,c);
     }
      }catch (Exception cause) {
    StackTraceElement elements[] = cause.getStackTrace();
    
    for (int i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; i++) {

Comment: System.err.println(elements[i].getFileName()
            + ":" + elements[i].getLineNumber() 
            + ">> "
            + elements[i].getMethodName() + "()");
    }
}

Comment: i run this, i get prompted for input
i enter 2 input Strings:
a
b

the program terminates, without asking for the third String(1 more input)

generating the following output

a,,b  
a,,b  
a,,b   

i'm absolutely convinced it's not my code but some software that has gone awry

PS. i tried using System.err.println(cause.printStackTrace());
    

it generated a compile error saying void type not allowed here

i'm thinking about uninstalling everything and then re-installing it

Comment: @RiteshBhakre How are you running it.. Through IDE, through command? I ran in on NetBeans and this updated code seems fine.

Comment: I'm running it on JCreator......

till yesterday, codes like these used to execute seamlessly for me as well...this issue has been pestering me since today.....
do you think re-installing jdk will make any difference?

Comment: No it is not a JDK problem. Could be JCreator... Try running it directly from command line...

Comment: boy, that worked wonders for me....this baby executes just fine from command line...behaves aberrantly if you rely on JCreator...many thanks Sir, i can finally sleep peacefully now! =)

Answer (score 0):

An exception from within `nextInt()` suggests that the issue is with the input -- that the program was fed five lines followed by something that is not an integer.

Examining the exception type should help you determine this.  You should be receiving either `InputMismatchException` (read something that isn't an integer) or `NoSuchElementException` (there is no more input to read).